# Error Inserting: no such table error

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I was trying to insert a text into a database. but i was not successful in creating the table. I am getting `Error Inserting:.... no such table`.

My database class.

```
package com.msvd.form;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataBase {
static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
static final String KEY_NAME= "name";

static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE="contactlist";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

static final String DATABASE_CREATE ="create table contactlist(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
        +"name text not null);";

Context context;
DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DataBase(Context cxt){
    this.context = cxt;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

}
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

public DataBase open(){
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Database open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Database close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public long insert(String name){
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
    value.put(KEY_NAME,name);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, value);

}

}
```

I created a edittext field in fragment_main.xml as follow

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.msvd.form.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="222dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="116dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_Save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_Name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my mainactivity class contains,

```
package com.msvd.form;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        private EditText et_name;
        private Button bt_save;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            final Context thiscontainer = container.getContext();
            et_name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_Name);
            bt_save = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_Save);
            final DataBase db = new DataBase(thiscontainer);
            bt_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    db.open();
                    db.insert(et_name.getText().toString());
                    db.close();

                }

            }); 



            return rootView;
        }

    }

}
```

and i am getting the error as:

```
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054): Error inserting name=aaaa
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: contactlist: , while compiling: INSERT INTO contactlist(name) VALUES (?)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.acquireAndLock(SQLiteStatement.java:260)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:112)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at com.msvd.form.DataBase.insert(DataBase.java:64)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at com.msvd.form.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:77)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-13 20:54:28.872: E/SQLiteDatabase(5054):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.msvd.form"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.msvd.form.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.msvd.form.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.msvd.form.MainActivity"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please suggest me how can i create the database table.

Comment: check for errors in your OnCreate() method where you exec() your create statement!

Comment: Uninstall your app to recreate the db in case you've renamed the table from an older version of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is at creating the table.

```
static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
static final String KEY_NAME= "name";

static final String DATABASE_NAME="MyDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE="contactlist";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

CHANGE FROM THIS

static final String DATABASE_CREATE ="create table contactlist(_id integer primary key     autoincrement,"
    +"name text not null);";

TO THIS

static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
+ DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ KEY_NAME + " text not null);";
```

Comment: thank you @Dushyant. the code worked. can i know what was the issue in my code?